# Why isn't my attribute value printing correctly to the shell in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

This feels very simple but I can't find the solution anywhere...

I have an object (question) defined as an instance of my Question model. It has the attribute 'type' which has 2 options. When querying it in the shell, I can see the correct attribute value, but when I try to print this value I get 'None'. This is affecting one of my views as I need to call a different html template depending on the type of question.

e.g.:

```
question=Question.objects.get(id=24)
q_type = question.type
```

When I call *q_type*, the correct attribute *['Single']* is printed to shell ,

When I call *print(q_type)*, *None* (with no quotation marks) is printed to shell

Feel like I'm missing something obvious here.. please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are interacting with the shell, instead of `print()` I would try

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write(q_type)
```